# i need to draw a whatever shape on a form and repeat it for each 5 seconds

Tags: c#

my code is like this :

```
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd_X = new Random();
        Random rnd_Y = new Random();
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, Convert.ToInt16(rnd_X.Next(250, 500)), Convert.ToInt16(rnd_Y.Next(250, 500)), 50, 50);
    }
```

what i need to do to is to draw rectangles on the form each 5 seconds but i need a 'PaintEventArgs' to draw, and the timer giving me a parameter EventArgs and i cant draw with it,

'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Graphics' and no extension method 'Graphics' accepting a first argument of type 'EventArgs' could be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different situations where a form must be redrawn, that are not controlled by your application. I.e. when the form is resized or moved, when parts of the form were hidden and now become visible and so on. In these cases, the `Paint` event is triggered and the `Form_Paint` method will be executed.

If you draw inside `Timer_Tick`, your shapes will not be redrawn immediately in these cases. Instead they will only appear at the next timer tick.

Therefore, it is better to put your drawing logic inside the paint routine and to tell the form to redraw itself at timer ticks. You can do so by calling `Invalidate`. Windows then will redraw the form as soon as your application is idle. If you call `Refresh` instead, this will trigger the paint method immediately. So, your `Timer_Tick` should really only call

```
Refresh();
```

And do all the painting in the paint routine.

---

Create the `Random` generator only once, i.e. make it a field in the form:

```
private readonly Random _rnd = new Random();
```

The problem is that when you create the `Random` object each time. It will start with a new sequence of random numbers each time. If you create it once it will yield the next random number of the sequence. You created 2 separate random number generators for the X and Y. Since they use the current time to initialize the sequence, and since the time clock ticks much slowlier than the CPU clock, the two random number generators might yield the same number! You will get a much better result by having one single generator.

---

Also, instead of subscribing its own event, a form can just override its own paint routine. This is the preferred way. Don't forget to call `base.OnPaint(e);` in order to let the form do the other drawing stuff.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, _rnd.Next(250, 500),
                                            _rnd.Next(250, 500), 50, 50);
}
```

There is no need to call `Convert.ToInt16`, since the `Next` function returns an `int` and `FillRectangle` expects ints as well.

Comment: You're genius I noticed that the drawing is to only two diffrent places and not according to the timer, i'll check it later.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

Assuming you have a `Form` you want to paint to, you can either

1. Trigger a `Refresh` on the form on each timer tick and use the `Paint`-Event
2. Get the Graphics Context for the form and use it for drawing.

1st option:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Refresh();
}



Form1_Paint( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
{
    Random rnd_X = new Random();
    Random rnd_Y = new Random();
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, Convert.ToInt16(rnd_X.Next(250, 500)), Convert.ToInt16(rnd_Y.Next(250, 500)), 50, 50);
}
```

2nd option:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle);
    Random rnd_X = new Random();
    Random rnd_Y = new Random();
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, Convert.ToInt16(rnd_X.Next(250, 500)), Convert.ToInt16(rnd_Y.Next(250, 500)), 50, 50);
}
```

In both scenarios I assume, you want to paint on the same form containing your `timer`-component.

If you don't want to draw an *additional* form onto the already existing one, I recommend calling `graphics.Clear(SystemColors.Window)` prior to drawing your rectangle.

Comment: i dont really think this will help i'll try

Comment: thanks alot♥
after a hour of trying to get a way to make something return a PaintEventArgs i got the way, i can do it by the parameter that on the Form1_Paint and return it to timer2_Tick function 
thank you alot